# Apply regex to catch specific bullets from list with header

Tags: regex, exception, bulletedlist

I am trying to catch specific list items with regex:

```
> check listId
> - [v] catch me
> - [x] skip me
> - [ ] catch me too

> ignore thislistId
> - [v] ignore me
> - [x] ignore me also
> - [ ] ignore me too
```

Expected matched result is

```
> - [v] catch me
> - [ ] catch me too
```

This regex works, except like this the regex ignores the listId:

```
\> - \[(v| )\]\s?[a-z].*\n?
```

If I precede with a non-capturing group on the listId, the output breaks after the first bullet:

```
(?:\> check listId\n)(\> - \[(v| )\]\s?[a-z].*\n?)
```

What is a better approach?

Comment: Try `>(?: - \[[v ]])?\s?[a-z].*\n?`

Comment: So, something like `(?<=^> check listId(?:\n> - .*)*\n)> - \[[v ]]\s?[a-z].*\n?`, right? https://regex101.com/r/6wakqm/1

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use Javascript (dataviewjs in Obsidian). Is it possible to 'stitch' all matches together into one result, using the regex (perhaps with code or flags)?

Comment: No, it is only possible with the code itself.

Comment: So, I posted the regex with explanation, if you need more help, please let know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/(?<=^> check listId(?:\n> - .*)*\n)> - \[[v ]]\s?[a-z].*\n?/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wakqm/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=^> check listId(?:\n> - .*)*\n)`
- `> - \[[v ]]` - a `> - [v]` or `> - [ ]` substring
- `\s?` - n optional whitespace
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `.*\n?` - the rest of the line and an optional newline char.